React Audio Recorder returns null for recorded audio in useState hook
I am building a registration form in React where users can input their username and record audio using the react-audio-voice-recorder library. I am using the useState hook to manage the state of the recorded audio blob, but it's returning null when I try to access it in the handleSubmit function.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { AudioRecorder } from 'react-audio-voice-recorder';

const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [recordedAudio, setRecordedAudio] = useState(null);

  const handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleRecordingComplete = (blob) => {
    console.log("Recording completed:", blob);
    setRecordedAudio(blob);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!username || !recordedAudio) {
      alert('Please enter a username and record audio before submitting.');
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Username: ${username}`);
    console.log(`Recorded Audio Blob:`, recordedAudio);

    // Code to submit username and recorded audio for registration

    setUsername('');
    setRecordedAudio(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Register
      </Typography>
      <TextField
        label="Username"
        variant="outlined"
        value={username}
        onChange={handleUsernameChange}
        fullWidth
        margin="normal"
      />
      <AudioRecorder
        onRecordingComplete={handleRecordingComplete}
        audioTrackConstraints={{
          noiseSuppression: true,
          echoCancellation: true,
        }}
        onNotAllowedOrFound={(err) => console.error(err)}
        downloadOnSavePress={false}
        showVisualizer={true}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;


When I try to access recordedAudio in the handleSubmit function, it returns null. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong in managing the state of the recorded audio blob?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Is handleRecordingComplete being called before the submit button is pressed?

Yes, I press stop recording button before press submit button

And console.log("Recording completed:", blob); logs something other than null for blob?

It can be done as this:
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
const Register = () => {
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const [recordedBlob, setRecordedBlob] = useState(null);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const startRecording = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorderRef.current = mediaRecorder;

    const chunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
      setRecordedBlob(blob);
      setIsRecording(false);
    };

    mediaRecorder.start();
    setIsRecording(true);
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorderRef.current && mediaRecorderRef.current.state === "recording") {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
  };

  const toggleRecording = () => {
    if (isRecording) {
      stopRecording();
    } else {
      startRecording();
    }
  };


The <AudioRecorder> component from react-audio-voice-recorder is designed so that the stop button throws away the recording, and will not call onRecordingComplete. You need to click the disk icon which will save it and call your function.
If you don't like that behavior, you could instead build your own ui, and still get the functionality you need from the useAudioRecorder() hook. To keep the recording, you call stopRecording(true)
const Example = () => {
  const { startRecording, stopRecording } = useAudioRecord();

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={startRecording}>Start</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => stopRecording(true)}>Stop and save</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => stopRecording(false)}>Abort</Button>
    </>
  )
}

